# embedding of video in latex beamer without frame

Tags: beamer, multimedia

There is a black beam above and below the video. Is there any idea, how i can cover it? 
And i would like to open the presentation with PDF Presenter Console instead of Okular. But with PDF Presenter the videos do not work.

```
\begin{frame}{\scshape Movment of particle}
   \begin{minipage}{100mm}
      This is a text, that explains the videos.
   \end{minipage}
   \hspace{7mm}
   \begin{minipage}{50mm}
      \movie[height = 4cm, width = 4cm, poster,loop, autostart]
      {}{move_video.wmv}
   \end{minipage}
   \begin{minipage}{50mm}
     \movie[height = 4cm, width = 4cm, poster,loop,autostart]
     {}{video2.wmv}
   \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

[image]
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of this "black beam"?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your video has a different aspect ratio then the one you are giving it. Try to adjust the values `height = 4cm` and `width = 4cm` to match the real proportion of your video. Maybe something like `height = 3cm` and `width = 4cm` (just a guess)